# Множественный Get-запрос(req.query), как добавить текущие значения get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Столкнулся с проблемой, на странице поиска собралось несколько GET- форм с постраничной навигацией, сортировкой и параметрами поискового запроса.

Проблема в том, что при отправке любой из этих форм, предыдущие значение GET стираются. Например пользователь выбрал в поиске "Ромашка" (?flower=romashka), а затем перешел на другую страницу и поисковой запрос пропал, осталось только (?page=2).

Собственно есть ли способ обработки GET-параметров? Перезаписи существующих (например sortby=Up на sortby=down) и добавлении к запросу новых, при получении.

Comment: а разве нельзя поиск организовать через `$_POST` ? Намного удобнее, и работы меньше

Comment: Нет, нельзя, пользователь не может сохранить пост в качестве ссылки и потом вернуться и пролистать ещё несколько страниц по своему запросу. К тому-же это не решает проблему навигации.

Comment: Ну так объедините их в одну форму и проблема решена.

Comment: каким образом можно объединить в одну форму разнесённые по разным частям страницы инпуты? Оо

Comment: @enhaster запросто - надо просто обернуть в `<form>` сразу всю страницу. Но я бы не рекомендовал так делать.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в каждую из форм параметры, нуждающиеся в сохранении, либо в виде скрытых полей - либо в виде части `action`:

```html
<form method=get>
  <input type=hidden name=flower value=romashka>

  <button name=sortby value=up>По возрастанию</button>
  <button name=sortby value=down>По убыванию</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Боюсь, что такой способ непродуктивен. Форма поиска состоит из кучи инпутов с массивами, к тому же их количество генерируется пользователем на странице...

Comment: @enhaster а другого способа и нет

Answer (score 0):

В общем, наиболее удобный вариант - это поставить на навигацию Jquery функции, которые будут клонировать значения страницы и добавлять скрытый инпут в поисковую форму, а затем её отправлять.

Comment: Только не забудьте, что при смене параметров фильтрации или сортировки номер страницы сохранять не надо.